# How to design User entity with avatar image in DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design

Basically I found 3 options:

- URL
- file ID
- bytes

But,

- URL can not be used in offline apps
- file ID forces me to make request to repository
- bytes take up a lot of memory

What is the best choice? What are pros and cos of each option?

Comment: It's not related to DDD. It's basically a question of opinion about software architecture.